# Change UniformGrid child item during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently trying to populate a UniformGrid in WPF.

Some context: I'm trying to build a 2D Sidescroller (I know, WPF is not the best solution to that and I should use Unity or something else. I'd like to try it though). Now, for the map I was thinking about using a UniformGrid and using the children as tiles for my map.

So far, I'm adding empty children to the UniformGrid using this piece of code:

```
private void CreateMapTiles() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 45; j++) {
            this.MapGrid.Children.Add(new Image());
        }
    }
}
```

Where `MapGrid` is my UniformGrid.

So, in the end, I want to have 30x45 children.
Now I want to dynamically edit those children in CodeBehind, i.e. make those children an image. Or put another way, I want to update, let's say, the child at index 5 to display another image from my resources, than it did before.

I was thinking about using something like this:

```
this.MapGrid.Children[1] = new Image() { Source = ReturnSomeSource() };
```

But for obvious reasons, this doesn't work.

Is there any way i can assign a value to the children during runtime?
I've also played around with `this.MapGrid.Children[1].SetCurrentValue()` a bit, but neither did I really understand what I was doing, nor did it work in any way.

Does the possibility even exist, to change the UniformGrid children during runtime?
Would a normal Grid do a better job? I wanted to avoid that, because the UniformGrid children are arranged and sized automatically the way i need them without any more effort.

Comment: This would be significantly easier with the MVVM pattern using data binding.  Use an `ItemsControl` bound to an `ObservableCollection` with a `UniformGrid` as its container.  Just add / edit / remove items from the collection and the UI will automatically adjust.

Comment: I fear i know nothing about MVVM patterns really, but I guess I should give it a read, because it sounds like a nice way to handle this. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than replacing `Image`with a new `Image`, change the source on the already existing image.

```
var tileImage = this.MapGrid.Children[1] as Image; 
tileImage.Source = ReturnSomeSource();
```